# Use overloaded delete operator with custom parameters

Tags: c++

I am overloading `new` and `delete` operator with custom parameters. While `new` works, i can't call `delete` with the custom parameters. I read somewhere that overloaded `delete` is called only if constructor of the object being created throws. If this is the case, is there no way to call my overloaded `delete` ?

```
void *operator new(size_t size, unsigned int Tag)
{
    //allocate and return.
    return nullptr;
}

void operator delete(void *ptr, size_t size, unsigned int Tag) 
{
    //deallocate
}

int main()
{
    int *arr = new(123) int;
    delete(123) arr;
}


error: type 'int' argument given to 'delete', expected pointer
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't explicitly call the *operator delete* overload (i.e. *placement delete*) using *delete expression*. In the *placement new* you should save the `Tag` somewhere and restore it in the *operator delete* and deallocate the memory properly.

Answer (score 2):

> is there no way to call my overloaded `delete` ?

Yes, you can't do it explicitly.

Here's an explanation from *[Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876)* (Scott Meyers, 3rd Edition), *Item 52: Write placement delete if you write placement new*

> However, consider what happens if no exception is thrown (which will
>   usually be the case) and we get to a `delete` in client code:
>
> ```
> delete pw;                            // invokes the normal
>                                       // operator delete
> ```
>
> As the comment indicates, this calls the normal `operator delete`, not
>   the placement version. Placement `delete` is called *only* if an exception
>   arises from a constructor call that's coupled to a call to a placement
>   `new`. Applying `delete` to a pointer (such as `pw` above) never yields a
>   call to a placement version of `delete`. *Never*.
>
> This means that to forestall all memory leaks associated with
>   placement versions of `new`, you must provide both the normal `operator delete` (for when no exception is thrown during construction) and a
>   placement version that takes the same extra arguments as `operator new`
>   does (for when one is).

Comment: So there is no way to get hold of `Tag` in my `delete` until and unless it is the exception scenario? If so, then the only way is to do some book keeping around the allocated pointer to retrieve it in my `delete`.

Comment: @user3819404 Yes, as the quotes said, you have to provide normal `operator delete` to perform such things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are defining **placement-new**, since your new syntax only match that one. In case of **placement-delete**, it is stated that:

> If defined, called by the custom single-object placement new
>   expression with the matching signature if the object's constructor
>   throws an exception. ([delete-operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete))